# How to accelerate C#/Linq query? [i don't need to get data, i need to get condition]

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

```
    public int being = 0;
    public void Insert(Currency current, int number)
    {
        being = db.Currency.Where(x => x.ForDate == current.ForDate)
            .Where(x => x.TitleId == current.TitleId)
            .Where(x => x.Value == current.Value).Count(x=>x.Id > 0);
        if (being == 0)
        {
            db.Currency.AddOrUpdate(current);
        }
   }
```

it's my code works so slowly, because of getting date but it is not necessary, i don't know other way.
maybe something like :

```
db.Currency.Find().Value.Equals(current.Value).where...where...
```

Comment: `db.Currency.AddOrUpdate(current);` works on the key you've defined for your entity, as far as I can tell from the snippet, it doesn't really make sense what you're doing. You can most likely replace the entire method with simply `db.Currency.AddOrUpdate(current)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think your main problem is the `.Count(x => x.Id > 0)`, which forces the evaluation of all the conditions before and actually get the total number.

If you can, replace it with `Any`. In that way, it just has to get one row at most:

```
bool isBeing = db.Currency
               .Where(x => x.ForDate == current.ForDate
                           && x.TitleId == current.TitleId
                           && x.Value == current.Value
                           && x.Id > 0
                     )
               .Any();
```

Comment: Yes, Any translates into "Exists" at the database level and will be faster. It can be a little more faster to change conditions inside where block to hit first in most scenarios.

Comment: Indeed, and for the database performance: `exists` is a lot faster than `count` for the reason mentioned.

Comment: @Decastrio: need more help?

Answer (score 4):

You can do all your conditions in just one `where`, and also you can skip having a `bool` variable to check your conditions

```
if(db.Currency.Where(x => x.ForDate == current.ForDate 
          && x.TitleId == current.TitleId && x.Value == current.Value && x.Id > 0).Any())
{
    db.Currency.AddOrUpdate(current);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't matter with EF, which groups all where's in a select statement.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I didn't notice the whole code I guess. I edited the whole condition

Comment: Why did you copy the key part of my answer? (The use of `Any`)

Comment: @PatrickHofman I didn't copy! I simply just haven't noticed the condition part. It's obvious for some people what `Any` does. *(Including me)*